# Job queue in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, sqlite, excel

Scenario:
I need a few machines to process cases from a database on an NFS in SQLite and stores the results on their own local drives.
Currently, I have a queue on a separate file which looks like this (the ids are just a distinct list of jobs that need to be processed):

```
id  | status
123 |   0 (not processed)
213 |   1 (in processing)
312 |   2 (processed)
```

The problem with doing

```
BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION;
SELECT id FROM queue WHERE status = 0 LIMIT 1;
(application stores the id as a variable)
UPDATE queue SET status = 1 WHERE id = variable;
COMMIT;
```

is that the file locking on SQLite is not reliable on a network drive and it ends up locking out all machines that are trying to check the status of the queue. I have set the VBA code to retry the transaction if the database is locked after waiting for a set amount of time but this does not work due to the locking problem.

I am wondering if there is any other way to achieve this by having a centralised controller which allocates jobs and updates the queue accordingly and whether is this possible in VBA?

Thanks.

Comment: A DB server could easily do just that. Don't you have a central DB server which can be accessed from all local machines? MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle's DB with PL/SQL, SAP's with MaxDB, etc. They all will do.

Comment: The environment that I am operating in does not make it possible for any server based solution to be set up. The only solution would be to go down a file-based route.